# Changing Text of asp:Button using Jquery

Tags: jquery, aspbutton

Am trying  to change text of an asp:Button using jQuery Like this

```
  $("#<%=delButton.ClientID%>").attr('text', 'InActivate');
  .....
  <asp:Button ID="delButton" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Activate "    
   CssClass="button"   ToolTip="" OnClientClick="ondel();return false;"/>
```

I can see the text changing, Is the proper way to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is shorter ;)

```
$("#<%=delButton.ClientID%>").val('InActivate');
```

Comment: The only note I would make to this is that if the object created is 
    <button> 
and not 
    <input type="button"> than this doesn't work. You could then use 
    $("#<%=delButton.ClientID%>").text('InActivate');

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the best way I know of. This will get you the right client id regardless of [clientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx):

```
<%= delButton.ClientID %>
```